# Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v2/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xx: unknown: Unable to parse json key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, drone.io

I am trying to pull a private GCR image from my CD tool (DroneIO), but the following error is generated.

**Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v2/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xx: unknown: Unable to parse json key.**

I am using the json file that is generated when I create the service account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you followed the steps described in https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json_key_file? From the error message, it seems the json key may be invalid somehow or maybe there is some wrong with the way you pipe the json key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a problem with the json file. It is already solved